# Can't center animated div with Animate.CSS or other animation libraries

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to center a div in the page and animate it, but

```
transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
```

will not work at all so it is only relying on the default

```
top: 50%; left: 50%
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <link href="http://www.exaltedweb.com/refs/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="stylesheets/admin2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="modal-wrapper" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; display:block;">
            <div class="modal-background" style=""></div>
            <div class="modal-content animated bounceIn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal-wrapper{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.modal-background{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    display:block;
}

.modal-content{
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    position: absolute; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I've tried a ton of things like display: block; and a bunch of other methods I found online, but none of those methods have works. Any help with this would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on this issue for an entire day. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't include the animate.css library in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle "jsfiddle.net/SolaceInfotech/7sj2ma2m/3/" to set html element at center of page. Do change height within #container {}

if you want to set element at center for specific size of block. Else do set it to 100% so your block will display at center of whole page.

It is tested in Chrome, Opera and Firefox and working fine with these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The animation classes from animate.css include transform statements which override the ones you are using to center the div. Use a wrapper div which is the full width and height of the container, and apply the animation classes to the wrapper.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper animated slideInDown">
    <div id="target" class="box " id="bluebox">
      <p>DIV #1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1pveopct/